# Oracle SQL Sort two Columns values connected to each other

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

My table is as below

```
CC1  CC2
675  876
123  987
453  123
876  453
987  432
```

Desired result

```
CC1  CC2
675  876
876  453
453  123
123  987
987  432
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the sort order you are looking for. It seems random (not the sum of the two columns). What have you tried and what results are you getting?

Comment: Its not random.  The value in col2 should be in col1 in the next row.

Comment: @smavizag i understood your question. As i don't know about your table and columns . i added answer with sample table information.

Answer (score 0):

sql Hierarchical queries

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, manager_id
   FROM employees
   CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;
```

refer to https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52335

Answer (score 0):

You need to use <kbd>[hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)</kbd> as

```
select cc1 , cc2 
  from tab
 start with cc1 = 675
connect by prior cc2 = cc1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c3f19857a1b2f4618f5d5745b4c6025)</kbd>

**Update :** Yes, What you offered is such a good relation to determine the root dynamically, or

```
select * 
  from tab 
 start with CC1 = (select CC1 
                     from tab t 
                    where not exists (select CC1
                                        from tab
                                       where CC2 = t.CC1 )) 
connect by prior CC2 = CC1
```

is also possible.

Comment: you're welcome @smavizag , but we need to use `start with` by definition, even using `level` pseudocolumn does not help us for such an hierarchical ordering. If `start with` is omitted, then the result set would start with the least value of `cc1` which is 123

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros. The new query works great. I was trying  "start with CC1 = (select CC1 from t where CC1 not in (select CC2 from t))"

Comment: Btw, you can add as an alternative answer @smavizag